# Installing libssl0.9.7 on Debian (Google Compute Engine)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am quite new to this. Is there a certain repo I'm supposed to install? If so could you tell me it and what command I need to put in. Thanks.
 libssl0.9.7 on Debian.

Comment: OpenSSL 0.9.7 is a very old version, vulnerable to Heartbleed and a great many other security issues. Can you go into some better detail on what exactly you're trying to do, and why you need this specific version?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any repos that still have that version. Installing such an old version of OpenSSL is NOT recommended as it comes with way too many vulnerabilities to list. But if you still want that version, you can download it here: http://archive.debian.net/etch/amd64/libssl0.9.7-dbg/download

Here are the commands to install it:

- wget -c http://archive.kernel.org/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/o/openssl097/libssl0.9.7-dbg_0.9.7k-3.1etch5_amd64.deb
- sudo dpkg -i libssl0.9.7*.deb
- sudo apt-get -f install

Since it's an old version, there's no guarantee that it'll be compatible with new systems. You may receive some errors after completing the installation.